# ProjectTo<ViewModel> Automapper version issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, automapper

I'm having a problem with the new version of Automapper v10.1.1 In the oldest versions there was the ProjectTo method. So right now at the moment, my issue is in one of the controllers at the **IActionResult Index**.

The error is at the postQuery and the error is **Error CS1501 No overload for method 'ProjectTo' takes 0 arguments**

```
public IActionResult Index(PaginationVM pagination, PostFilterVM postFilter)
        {
            if (this.HasAlert)
            {
                this.SetAlertModel();
            }

            //here is the error
            var postsQuery = this.FilterPosts(postFilter, this.salePostService.GetAll().ProjectTo<PostVM>());

            var paginatedPosts = this.PaginateList<PostVM>(pagination, postsQuery).ToList();

            foreach (var post in paginatedPosts)
            {
                post.Sneaker.PosterImageRelativeLink = FileManager.GetRelativeFilePath(post.Sneaker.PosterImageLink);
                post.Sneaker.OverallRating = post.Sneaker.Ratings.Any() ? post.Sneaker.Ratings.Average(s => s.Rating.Score) : 0;
            }

            int totalPages = this.GetTotalPages(pagination.PageSize, postsQuery.Count());

            PostListVM postListViewModel = new PostListVM
            {
                Posts = paginatedPosts,
                NextPage = pagination.Page < totalPages ? pagination.Page + 1 : pagination.Page,
                PreviousPage = pagination.Page > 1 ? pagination.Page - 1 : pagination.Page,
                CurrentPage = pagination.Page,
                TotalPages = totalPages,
                ShowPagination = totalPages > 1,
            };

            this.LoadListSneakersDropdowns(postFilter);

            return this.View(postListViewModel);
        }
```

I would be grateful if you could help me with this issue, because I read all the documentation and I still can't find the right way to fix it...
**Thanks in advance!!**

Answer (score 2):

This is a working production code right now using ProjectTo.

```
public async Task<GetDocumentsResponse> Handle(GetDocumentsRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    //// Omitted code

    var query = _databaseContext.Documents
        .Where(x =>
            x.ScenarioId== request.ScenarioId
            && x.IsMandatory);

    var result = _mapper.ProjectTo<Document>(query).ToList();

    return new GetDocumentsResponse
    {
        Documents = result,
    };
}
```

I would suggest that you inject or new up an instance of mapper and then project the result that way

Comment: Okay, but when I add an new instance at the 
`var postsQuery = this.FilterPosts(postFilter, this.salePostService.GetAll());
var result = _mapper.ProjectTo<PostVM>(postsQuery).ToList();`
I can't convert the types from _System.Linq.IQueryable<Domain.Models.SalePost>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Web.ViewModels.SalePosts.PostVM>_

Comment: when you add that, what do you get?

Comment: make your model object an IEnumerable and that should sort that out for you